Are patents often drafted and worded with the expectation that potential licensees would read it?
Besides the specifications of the invention, patents often contain sections comparing the invention to prior art, making the case for the invention as an improvement.
I am wondering if this section is actually meant to impress potential licensees, investors, or buyers, rather than the patent examiner?

A comparison of an invention to the “prior art” is no longer favored by many practitioners in the U.S.
First, prior art is a term that is avoided at all cost. Any comparison invites judges to import criteria into class a that aren’t in the claims. You might say “my invention is better than thing XYZ because XYZ is bigger than a breadbasket.”
You might have no mention of miniaturization in a claim but a judge might say an infringer doesn’t infringe because their product is large and you said your invention is not large. (A bad example because size itself is not generally a patent limitation).
In any case it is not to signal anything to potential licensees. You need to approach them with your pitch.
Potential potential licensees can be encouraged (and potential infringers deterred) by a well written, professional document with broad, easy to understand and defensible claims.

Why is it no longer preferred to compare with prior art?

See improved answer
